# Como puedo mostrar un badge notification en el icono de mi app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

estoy desarollando una app que recibe notificaciones desde un servidor, al recibir una nueva notificacion...  me gustaria que aparezca un badge de notificacion ( NO ES NECESARIO QUE SE AUTO INCREMENTA) en el icono de  la app  y tambien dentro de una activity desde un imageView y al leer la notificacion , que desaparezca el badge de ambos lugares
Mi codigo donde recibo las notificaciones:

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
        enviarNotificacion(remoteMessage);
    }
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Body notification: "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        enviarNotificacion(remoteMessage);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy ");
    String strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String title = data.get("title");
    String body = data.get("body");
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Acc";
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alerta.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("body", body);
    CharSequence channelName = "Acc";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setTicker("Acc ")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo("info");
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
   /* AddData(strDate,body,title);
    SelectData();*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es importante comentar que el despliegue de un "Badge" en las notificaciones únicamente es posible para dispositivos Android 8.0 o posterior.

Lo que necesitas es básicamente crear un `NotificationChannel`  y asignarlo a tu `NotificationManager`:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        //Crea NotificationChannel
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "notificaciones", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        mChannel.setDescription("canal default");
        mChannel.setShowBadge(true);

        //Asigna el canal a NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
```

en tu `NotificationCompat.Builder` define las propiedades:

```
            .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
            .setNumber(12). //Define el número de elementos.
```

Revisa la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

El código sería:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy ");
    String strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String title = data.get("title");
    String body = data.get("body");
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Acc";
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alerta.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("body", body);
    CharSequence channelName = "Acc";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        //Crea NotificationChannel
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "notificaciones", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        mChannel.setDescription("canal default");
        mChannel.setShowBadge(true);

        //Asigna el canal a NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setTicker("Acc ")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

            //Badge, muestra 12 elementos:
            .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
            .setNumber(12)

            .setContentInfo("info");
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys me ayudo mucho tu respuesta, aun no me soluciono mi pregunta , porque mi dispositivo tiene un api bajo del 26, y el despliegue del badge arranca con 26 , según lo que leí por eso no me funciona. muchas gracias